# wpf Datagrid force datagrid row evaluation

Tags: c#, wpf, validation, datagridview

I have a **DataGridView** that with a row validation property:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding SetupXml.Files.FileList}">
    <DataGrid.RowValidationRules>
        <vm:FileServerValidation ValidationStep="CommittedValue"/>
    </DataGrid.RowValidationRules>
</DataGrid>
```

Whenever the User changes a value in the DataGridView (and commits it) my **ValidationRule** is called:

```
public override ValidationResult Validate(object value, CultureInfo cultureInfo)
{
    if (!(value is BindingGroup bg))
        return ValidationResult.ValidResult;
    foreach (var item in bg.Items)
    {
        if (!(item is FileServer c))
            continue;

        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(c.FileServerName))
            return new ValidationResult(false, "File server name is empty");

        if (c.FileServerName.Length < 3)
            return new ValidationResult(false, "File server name is to short");
    }

    return ValidationResult.ValidResult;
}
```

Due to various reasons I would like to trigger a complete validation of the grid whenever the user clicks a **submit** button.

Therefore I wrote a function that gets the **ErrorStatus** of all DataGridRows.

```
public static bool HasInvalidRows(DataGrid datagrid)
{
    var valid = true;
    foreach (var item in datagrid.ItemContainerGenerator.Items)
    {
        var evaluateItem = datagrid.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(item);
        if (evaluateItem == null) continue;

        valid &= !System.Windows.Controls.Validation.GetHasError(evaluateItem);
    }

    return !valid;
}
```

The problem is: the ValidationRule is not called for every row but only for those rows that were changed. This way if some of the data in a row was inserted through a master detail section, some rows might not have been evaluated and the **Validation.GetHasError** will return a not evaluated result which defaults to true.

Do you have any idea how to accomplish that?

Comment: You can call a non-public method using reflection. But what you should do is to implement the `INotifyDataErrorInfo` interface along with your validation logic in the `FileServer` class.

Comment: Do you know if it's possible to force evaluate a row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found my own answer now:

Each `DataGridRow` has a `BindingGroup`. Further information on can be found [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.bindinggroup(v=vs.110).aspx).

Whenever the `BindingGroup.CommitEdit()` is called, the validation executes.

Note that I have set the `ValidationStep` to `CommittedValue` in the xaml row validation Tag.

```
public static bool HasInvalidRows(DataGrid datagrid)
{
    var valid = true;
    foreach (var item in datagrid.ItemContainerGenerator.Items)
    {
        var evaluateItem = datagrid.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(item);
        if (evaluateItem == null) continue;

        if (!(evaluateItem is DataGridRow dgr)) continue;

        dgr.BindingGroup.CommitEdit();

        valid &= !System.Windows.Controls.Validation.GetHasError(evaluateItem);
    }

    return !valid;
}
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: Note that this approach won't work for virtualized rows.

Comment: Using a series of Not Logic can be confusing... I found it better to name it AreRowsValid and return valid instead of !valid.