# WPF Datagrid -- How to force commit of data in row?

Tags: wpf, datagrid, commit, itemssource

How can I force a commit when a datagrid row loses focus as opposed to requiring the user to press return to commit?

I have a MVVM project with a main `DataGrid` using a `RowDetailsTemplate` that contains another sub `DataGrid`.  It uses the default behavior of pressing 'Enter' on the row commits the value changes.  I have a `ValidatonRule` implemented for both the main row and the sub row.

Sub grid closed
[image]

Sub grid open
[image]

- Selecting an account from the ComboBox populates the main grid with transactions.  Clicking the [Sub] button opens the sub grid and shows the subtransactions for that transaction.
- If the user enters values in the transaction (main row) and presses 'Enter', the transaction values are successfully committed; i.e., the `Transaction ValdationStep.CommittedValue` is triggered.
- If the user enters values in the main row (doesn't press 'Enter') and just clicks the [Subs] button to open the sub grid, then enters values in the subtransaction and presses 'Enter', the subtransaction values are successfully committed; i.e., the `SubtransactionValidation ValdationStep.CommittedValue` is triggered.
- **But** if the user then clicks out of the sub grid without ever pressing 'Enter' on the main row, the values in the transaction are **not** committed; i.e., `Transaction ValdationStep.CommittedValue` is **never** triggered.  Then, when a new account is selected (which results in a change in the `ItemsSource` collection) a `CollectionChanged` event is triggered on `ItemsSource` to remove the source item (the uncommitted transaction) as if the user hit 'Esc'.

I assume the `CollectionChanged` event is triggered by the `DataGrid` deciding the row hadn't been committed and so removes it from the collection.

This [SO: Cancel collection changed event on an observable collection](http://wpf%20Datagrid%20force%20datagrid%20row%20evaluation) may be a way to cancel the `CollectionChanged` and removal of the item but it seems forcing the commit of the changes is more what is needed.  Plus, I'd have to figure out when to enable/disable when to ignore the event.

I thought this [SO: wpf Datagrid force datagrid row evaluation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51260464/wpf-datagrid-force-datagrid-row-evaluation) might be a solution (though overkill) and implemented it in the button code (see below) but it still triggered the `CollectionChanged` event to remove the item event when I select a different account and the `ItemsSource` collection is changed.

```
private void ToggleSubs_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ...
    foreach (var item in BankDataGrid.ItemContainerGenerator.Items)
    {
        var container = BankDataGrid.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(item);
        if (container != null && container is DataGridRow dgr)
        {
            dgr.BindingGroup.CommitEdit();
        }
    }
}
```

I then tried catching the `ValidationStep.ConvertedProposedValue` (which I found is triggered after clicking [Subs] button) and forcing `BindingGroup.CommitEdit()` on that row.  But when I selected a different account, once again the `CollectionChanged` event was triggered to remove the item.

XAML

```
<Grid>
    <Grid x:Name="MainPanel">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="26" />
            <RowDefinition Height="30" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        ...
        <Grid x:Name="Controls" Grid.Row="1" >
            ...
            <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                <Label Content="Account" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                <ComboBox Name="ControlsAccount" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="210"
                          ItemsSource="{Binding AccountList}" 
                          SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedAccount}"
                          IsEnabled="{Binding HasAccounts}" >
                    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" 
                                Foreground="{Binding ItemForeColor}" 
                                Background="{Binding ItemBackColor}" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                </ComboBox>
            </StackPanel>
            ...
        </Grid>
        <DataGrid x:Name="BankDataGrid" Grid.Row="2"
            ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedAccount.Transactions, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}"
            SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedAccount.SelectedTransaction, Converter={StaticResource TransConverter}}" >
            ...
            <DataGrid.RowValidationRules>
                <valid:BankTransactionValidation ValidationStep="UpdatedValue" />
                <valid:BankTransactionValidation ValidationStep="CommittedValue" />
            </DataGrid.RowValidationRules>
            ...
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                ...
            </DataGrid.Columns>

            <DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
                <DataTemplate x:Name="SubDataTemplate">
                    <DataGrid x:Name="SubDataGrid"
                        ItemsSource="{Binding Subtransactions}"
                        SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedSubtransaction, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Converter={StaticResource SubtransConverter}}" >
                        ...
                        <DataGrid.RowValidationRules>
                            <valid:SubtransactionValidation ValidationStep="UpdatedValue" />
                            <valid:SubtransactionValidation ValidationStep="CommittedValue" />
                        </DataGrid.RowValidationRules>
                        ...
                        <DataGrid.Columns>
                            ...
                        </DataGrid.Columns>
                    </DataGrid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
    ...
</Grid>
```

MainVM

```
partial class MainVM : BaseVM
{
    public MainVM()
    {
        LoadSettings();

        InitMainPanel();
        InitTransactionSearch();
        InitLookupMaintenance();
        InitLookupReplacement();
        InitAccountDetails();
        InitBusyPanel();
    }
    ...
    private ObservableCollection<AccountVM> accountList;
    public ObservableCollection<AccountVM> AccountList
    {
        get => accountList;
        set
        {
            accountList = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
    private AccountVM selectedAccount;
    public AccountVM SelectedAccount
    {
        get => selectedAccount;
        set
        {
            selectedAccount = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged();
            if (selectedAccount != null)
            {
                WindowTitle = $"{selectedAccount.Name} - {AppName}";
                BankDataGridVisibility = VISIBILITY_SHOW;
                BackgroundImageVisibility = VISIBILITY_HIDE;
                SubtransactionsVisibility = VISIBILITY_COLLAPSE;
                SubtransactionVM.XferAccountRemove(selectedAccount.Name, AccountList);
            }
            else
            {
                HideTransactions();
            }
            HasAccounts = (AccountList != null && AccountList.Count > 0) ? LITERAL_TRUE : LITERAL_FALSE;
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

AccountVM CollectionChanged handler for Transactions collection

```
public class AccountVM : BaseVM
{
    private ObservableCollection<BankTransactionVM> transactions;
    public ObservableCollection<BankTransactionVM> Transactions
    {
        get
        {
            if (transactions == null)
            {
                ReadTransactions();
            }
            return transactions;
        }
    }
    private BankTransactionVM selectedTransaction;
    public BankTransactionVM SelectedTransaction
    {
        get => selectedTransaction;
        set
        {
            selectedTransaction = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
    ...
    private void BankTransactions_CollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var action = e.Action;
        if (action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove)
        {
            foreach (BankTransactionVM item in e.OldItems)
            {
                // Notifiy parent of change for properties dependent upon collection items
                Transaction_PropertyChanged(item, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(TransactionsCount)));
                Transaction_PropertyChanged(item, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(TransactionsTotal)));

                // Remove the item
                item.Delete();
            }
        }
        else if (action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add)
        {
            foreach (BankTransactionVM item in e.NewItems)
            {
                // Add the item
                item.AccountId = AccountId;
                item.Insert();

                // Add the event handlers
                item.PropertyChanged += new PropertyChangedEventHandler(Transaction_PropertyChanged);
                item.TransferCreated += new TransferCreatedEventHandler(Transaction_TransferCreated);
                item.TransferDeleted += new TransferDeletedEventHandler(Transaction_TransferDeleted);

                // Notifiy parent of change for properties dependent upon collection items
                Transaction_PropertyChanged(item, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(TransactionsCount)));
                Transaction_PropertyChanged(item, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(TransactionsTotal)));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

BankTransactionValidation

```
public class BankTransactionValidation : ValidationRule
{
    public override ValidationResult Validate(object value, CultureInfo cultureInfo)
    {
        var result = ValidationResult.ValidResult;

        var bg = (BindingGroup)value;
        var row = (DataGridRow)bg.Owner;
        if (row.Item is BankTransactionVM item)
        {
            switch (ValidationStep)
            {
                case ValidationStep.RawProposedValue:
                    break;
                case ValidationStep.ConvertedProposedValue:
                    break;
                case ValidationStep.UpdatedValue:
                    break;
                case ValidationStep.CommittedValue:
                    if (item.TransactionId > 0)
                    {
                        item.Update();
                        if (item.Subtransactions.Count == 0)
                        {
                            item.Subtransactions.Add(new SubtransactionVM(item.TransactionId));
                        }
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the key was using DataGrid.CommitEdit() instead of BindingGroup.CommitEdit().  By using the following line in the `ToggleSubs_Click()` method, before reading in the data for the subgrid, it forces the same sequence as the user pressing [Enter] on the row.

```
DataGrid.CommitEdit(DataGridEditingUnit.Row, true)
```